# GCP Cloud Build Python Package

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, packaging, google-cloud-build

In [Google's documentation for cloud build Python packaging](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/configure-cloud-build#python), it says

> create a file named `requirements.txt` with the following dependencies

I'd really rather use the newer `pyproject.toml`, and ideally I'd like to use a pinned SHA of the package I'm using, like what `pdm.lock` creates.

Is it possible to use something besides `requirements.txt`?  The page I've linked to says nothing further.

Comment: With Cloud Build, do whatever you want, you are create your own script!